# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist OrderProduct

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, microservices

I'm learning microservices and while creating a database entry I got stuck on this error.

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: OrderProduct

When I change the cascading to MERGE then the data get saved in OrderDetail table only. I have searched but could not find a anything useful. Here's my code.

Feign Proxy Interface:

```
@FeignClient(name="product-metadata",url="localhost:8080")
public interface OrderProductProxy {
    @GetMapping("/products/productdetails/{productId}")
    public OrderProduct getProductDetails(@PathVariable UUID productId);
}
```

OrderDetail Entity:

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class OrderDetail {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    
    private UUID orderId;
    
    private String customerId;
    
    private String totalAmount;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "orderId")
    private List<OrderProduct> productId;

    public void addProduct(OrderProduct orderProduct) {
        if(orderProduct != null) {
            if(productId == null) {
                productId = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        this.productId.add(orderProduct);
        orderProduct.setOrderId(this);
    }
}
```

OrderProduct Entity:

```
@Getter @Setter
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class OrderProduct {
    
    
    private long id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID uniqueId;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orderId")
    private OrderDetail orderId;
}
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/create/{productId}")
    public OrderDetail createOrder(@PathVariable UUID productId,@RequestBody OrderDetail orderDetails) {
        
        OrderProduct orderProduct = proxy.getProductDetails(productId);
        System.out.println(orderProduct);
        orderDetails.addProduct(orderProduct);
        UUID orderId = UUID.randomUUID();
        orderDetails.setOrderId(orderId);
        return repo.save(orderDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating your method with `@Transactional`. Then then `OrderProduct` won't get detached within the `createOrder` method.

Comment: OP's code entirely based on anti-patterns, you suggest to add another one.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov your comment adds zero value